# How to prevent web browser from caching IMG tag that contains sensitive information?

Tags: php, html, image, security

In my PHP script I may generate a QR code that is used as a two-factor authentication private key for a user login. (Such QR code is shown **only** at the moment when user account is created.) The QR code itself is generated as an image as such:

```
<img src="https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=200x200&chld=M%7C0&cht=qr&chl=otpauth://totp/Example:alice@gmail.com?secret=TGABZXEP4LKB46AX&issuer=Example" alt="QR code">
```

Because this QR code contains sensitive information, I was wondering if there's a way to prevent web browsers from caching (or in any way saving) this image on the client's computer?

Comment: If someone presented me with such a QR code, the first thing I'd do is press `alt-print screen` and paste a copy into Photoshop so I could save it.  I would do this because I've experienced too many half-baked applications that show you something important but never let you get back to it if something goes wrong.

Comment: You could proxy request to the Google API and add a `Cache-Control: no-store` header. That will prevent browsers and intermediate proxies from caching the resource, but it won't prevent users from taking screenshots, storing the image, etc.

Comment: @BobBrown: Why would you do that? The whole idea of two-factor authentication is to provide you with means to save your private key outside of your computer.

Comment: @Bjorn: Good idea. Any suggestions how to proxy such request in PHP?

Comment: Via CURL: `<?php header('Cache-Control: no-store'); $ch = curl_init(); ....`

Comment: @c00000fd:  For exactly the reason I explained, too many half-baked applications.  I was about to say, "not to imply that *your* application is half-baked..." but if I am to save a QR code outside my computer, you've assumed I have a printer available.  You're going to have to get used to the idea that if you send something to a client computer, the person operating that computer can manipulate what you sent.

Comment: @BobBrown: Printer? No. It's intended for your smartphone, or Google Authenticator app, per se. And yes, I get it that some users don't understand computer security and will attempt to print it out, email it to themselves or do some other similar "thing."

Comment: @Bjorn: Thanks, but shouldn't it be `Cache-Control: no-cache` instead?

Comment: @c00000fd: No, check: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/images/http-cache-decision-tree.png